# I need to read the pdf content as it is there in the pdf as c# tables

Tags: c#, pdf, extract

I need to read the pdf content as it is there in the pdf as c# tables

So that I can get the values for the keys I needed. Please suggest me any better idea

thanks in adavance

What I have tried:

I have tried ITextSharp but it is giving only the entire content at a time.

Comment: Hi, your question as it is is marked as too broad and unclear. Can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: hi stefan,,  I want to read the PDF content in C# application and I am able to read the entire thing as a string where each word is seperated with \n using itextsharp.

Comment: using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path))
            {     text = new StringBuilder();
                ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
                                
                for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
                {
                    text.Append(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i, strategy));
                }
                               
                return text.ToString();
            }

Comment: am trying to read the tables formatted content which will have the invoice data for suppose for different vendors into C# data tables for find the values of particular fields

Comment: Hi, I think it's best to ask your question again and delete this one. Make sure you include your code in the original post.

Comment: Is your pdf tagged?

Comment: Use [GemBox.Document](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document), it can recognize Table structures in PDF files based on the positioned text and lines/paths. See [this example](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/examples/c-sharp-read-pdf/305).